# SQL Server trigger active card

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, triggers

I have the following tables:

- Cards (IDCard, IDPerson, Balance, Active)
- Persons (IDPerson)

Every time a new card is inserted, I need to check if that card already belongs to a person. If so, I need to change the active to false and the new card must receive the balance of the previous card and the state must be true.

```
select count(c.IDPerson) 
from cards c, inserted i 
where c.IDPerson = i.IDPerson;

if @@ROWCOUNT > 0
begin
    print'this card already exists'

    select c.IDPerson, c.Balance, c.Active
    INTO #tmp
    FROM Cards c, inserted i
    where c.IDCard = i.IDCard

    update Cards
    set Active = 0
    from #tmp
    where #tmp.IDPerson = Cards.IDPerson;
end
```

When I insert a new record into cards table, the old card does turn false (0), however the new card also stays with active equal to false.
This in an after insert on cards table.

Can someone tell me how to fix the problem?

Comment: Where are you wanting to handle this? Are all your inserts going to be via an SP, for example?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: @Larnu, no it won't. I am testing with regular inserts. Insert into <table> values ...

Comment: You're likely going to want an `INSTEAD OF` trigger here then, however, I would much rather control the process of inserts by an SP.

Comment: And stop blindly applying a pattern for no particular reason. The <select into #tmp> approach should be chosen when it has a beneficial effect. In situations where a single statement can do everything you need this pattern often just creates extra work with no benefit.

Answer (score 2):

Although your trigger is running within the transaction, I think it is still capable of updating itself.

When you update where the INSERTED.IDPERSON = CARD.IDPERSON - this includes the record you have inserted; thus all records are updated to Active = false.

Rather, you should do

```
update Cards
set Active = 0
from #tmp
where #tmp.IDPerson = Cards.IDPerson
AND Cards.IDCARD != #tmp.IDCARD    --This is the new condition
```

I've created a copy of what I believe you are asking in this [DBFiddle Link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=640702fdc1af824f739fbf41144e38f9)

User marc_s is also correct in saying you should use JOIN syntax here. Your entire operation could be completed in one much cleaner statement

```
UPDATE c
SET c.Active = 0
FROM Cards c
INNER JOIN Inserted i
ON i.IDPERSON = c.IDPERSON
AND i.IDCARD != c.IDCARD
```

Answer (score 0):

The `if` is not appropriate.  Remember, that the trigger could be handling multiple rows at the same time.

An explicit `join` does the filtering you want.  This is a little complicated, but you can do it with two `join`s:

```
update c2
    set Active = (case when c2.IDCard = i.IDCard then 1 else 0 end)
    from Cards c 
         inserted i
         on c.IDCard = i.IDCard join
         Cards c2
         on c.IDPerson = c2.IDPerson;
```